# MYSQL PHP cannot insert or update with the same value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with two value.

ID, Building(is the name of Building)

i write a code with jquery to insert or Update the name of Building (i take the ID value from list1 and the new name from text_build)

```
function saveBuilding()
{
alert(document.getElementById("list1").value)
alert(document.getElementById("text_build").value)

$.get("saveBuilding.php",{ID:document.getElementById("list1").value,       val:document.getElementById("text_build").value}, 
function(ret) { alert(ret);});
}
```

where my saveBuilding is:

```
   <?php 
    $idbuilding=$_GET['ID'];
    $name=$_GET['val'];
    require_once '../../../dbconnection.php';
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    if (!db_server) die("Unable to connection_aborted to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_database) or die ("Unable to connection_aborted to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 

    $query = "UPDATE Building SET Name = '$name' WHERE ID_Building = '$idbuilding';"; 
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if (mysql_error()) {
             echo mysql_error();
        }   
    mysql_close(); 
    ?>
```

Now, if i update the value with a new value, it works, if i update the value with a value already used previously, it said that the query is successfully but it dont change nothing.

I try to insert new value by changing the query. and the result is the same.

i also try to add this value directly from mysql and it works!

so which is the problem in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Like what? but if i write that query on mysql command line it works..so i thing the problem is on the js o php code no?

Comment: This isn't a proper question, as noted by the user in his/her auto-answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem..

first i verified that the php code  works.

and then i verified that the problem was the js.

i dont know why but changing the jquery function $.get in $.post now it work!!

Comment: You don't know why but it's due to the fact that you were sending your form data using a different method than the one expected by your script. By the way, this have nothing to do with MySQL nor with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is working as designed (and other rdbms). If you try to change a value to its current value, no error is thrown but nothing happens.

You just need to run

SELECT Name FROM your_table WHERE idbuilding=$id

then compare Name to what is already stored. If it's different, run your UPDATE; if not don't do anything because no action is required.

Comment: Im sorry, I havent explained well, ill make an example.

Comment: If a value for example 'Building1' and i update it in: 'Building1'->'Building2'->'Building3'  it works  if i update it in:'Building1'->'Building2'->'Building1' it wont update the last change!

Comment: Please do DESCRIBE your_table and post the results here.

Comment: mysql> Describe Building;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Building | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name        | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: I'm beginning to think you're database is corrupted. That's a very basic table and definition of int and varchar.

Comment: i dont think so..as i said before if i insert the query from mysql command line. it works. if i do it from php it wont work.